# Attempting to apply the filterRows1 function to two different tabs without any sucess

Tags: google-apps-script

I am attempting to apply the filterRows1 function to two different tabs.

If I specify 1 tab in the script, it works fine without any issues.

When I add another tab, it works on the second tab but not the first.

I am using the below script.

```
function filterRows1(){
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive() .getSheetByName("Q1");
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive() .getSheetByName("Q2");
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
sheet.showRows(1, sheet.getMaxRows());
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
//If column C (3rd column) is "Y" then hide the row.
if(data[i][0] === "hide") {
sheet.hideRows(i + 1);
sheet.hideColumns(1);
}
}
}
```

I am using a separate onEdit function

```
function onEdit(e) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
var sheetNames = ["RPM", "PFS Kiosk"]
filterRows1()
}
```

Please advise.

Thank you.

I tried different way to add tabs name together but not getting anywhere.

Comment: * var sheetNames = ["Q1", "Q2] *

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between `* var sheetNames = ["Q1", "Q2] *` in your comment and your question. Can I ask you about the detail of your question? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.

I would like to use the FilterRow1 function to hide the rows where cells are empty. And function should work on edit. 

The function written in the question works fine if I apply it to only 1 tab (there are multiple tabs on the sheet). But having issues when applying to multiple tabs. 




Regarding the * var sheetNames = ["Q1", "Q2] *, I used this in the onedit function. 

On the app script, I created two files: one with the filterRow1 function and the other with the onEdit function.

I used this * var sheetNames = ["Q1", "Q2] * under the OnEdit file.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. I have 2 questions. 1. What is the relationship between `var sheetNames = ["RPM", "PFS Kiosk"]` and `var sheetNames = ["Q1", "Q2]`? 2. When `onEdit` is run, what do you want to do? Do you want to run the script with both 2 sheets? Or, do you want to run the script with only the active sheet including one of the 2 sheets you want to use? I deeply apologize that I am trying to correctly understand your question.

Comment: 1 - var sheetNames = ["RPM", "PFS Kiosk"] and var sheetNames = ["Q1", "Q2] are the same. The first one is the original name of the tabs on the sheet. Just to make it easier, I used Q1 and Q2.

2.  Yes, I want to run the script with both sheets at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. Although I thought that when the OnEdit trigger is used, the event object can be used, from your question and script, I thought that when the script of `filterRows1` can be individually run, it might be useful for your situation. So, I proposed a modified script. If I misunderstood your expected result, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- From `1 - var sheetNames = ["RPM", "PFS Kiosk"] and var sheetNames = ["Q1", "Q2] are the same. The first one is the original name of the tabs on the sheet. Just to make it easier, I used Q1 and Q2. 2. Yes, I want to run the script with both sheets at the same time.`, you want to run your script with both 2 sheets when the script of `filterRows1()` is run.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function filterRows1() {
  var sheetNames = ["Q1", "Q2"]; // Please set your sheet names.

  sheetNames.forEach(sheetName => {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
    if (!sheet) return;
    sheet.showRows(1, sheet.getMaxRows());
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
      if (data[i][0] === "hide") {
        sheet.hideRows(i + 1);
        sheet.hideColumns(1);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

- When this script is run, the script is run for both `var sheetNames = ["Q1", "Q2"];`.
- In this script, when the sheet names of `["Q1", "Q2"]` is not found in the active Spreadsheet, the sheet is skipped.

#### Reference:

- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Thank you very much. The function is working now on both sheets.

Comment: @Pothwari Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could correctly understand with your cooperation. Thank you, too.